# Cygwin - STunnel doesn't respond anymore

Tags: cygwin, stunnel

I long used **Cygwin** 64bit and cygwin's package **All/Net/stunnel: Universal TLS wrapper** on my Windows 10 machine very happily.

Suddenly however, STunnel doesn't respond anymore. I know it's very vague, so I'll provide some info below. I have installed version 5.31-1, but also tried with 5.28-1 to no avail.

```
$ # from the man page for stunnel, 
$ # -version should output version and compile time. 
$ # But nothing comes out. 
$  
$ stunnel -version
$ stunnel -help
$ type stunnel
stunnel is hashed (/usr/bin/stunnel)
$ which stunnel
/usr/bin/stunnel
$
```

The lack of output is driving me crazy, not sure why nothing comes out. I completely uninstalled cygwin - following the website guidelines -  then reinstalled cygwin and stunnel.

I suspect a missing library, but cygwin takes care of all dependancies, unless it's not and I really miss an important library. I have installed perl and openssh but still no luck.

```
$ cygcheck ../../bin/stunnel.exe
C:\cygwin64\bin\stunnel.exe
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygssp-0.dll
    C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
        C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
        C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
          C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-eventing-provider-l1-1-0.dll
        C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
        C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
        C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-xstate-l2-1-0.dll
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygcrypto-1.0.0.dll
    C:\cygwin64\bin\cygz.dll
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygssl-1.0.0.dll
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwrap-0.dll


$ ldd ../../bin/stunnel.exe
    ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffbd65b0000)
    KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffbd5890000)
    KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffbd2f90000)
    TmUmEvt64.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/tmumh/20019/AddOn/6.80.0.1007/TmUmEvt64.dll (0x7ffbd0350000)
    PSAPI.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/PSAPI.DLL (0x7ffbd39a0000)
    SHLWAPI.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/SHLWAPI.dll (0x7ffbd3d10000)
    msvcrt.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/msvcrt.dll (0x7ffbd5a50000)
    combase.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/combase.dll (0x7ffbd6200000)
    RPCRT4.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/RPCRT4.dll (0x7ffbd6490000)
    bcryptPrimitives.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/bcryptPrimitives.dll (0x7ffbd2e70000)
    GDI32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/GDI32.dll (0x7ffbd3a20000)
    USER32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/USER32.dll (0x7ffbd3db0000)
    ADVAPI32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/ADVAPI32.dll (0x7ffbd3f10000)
    sechost.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/sechost.dll (0x7ffbd5520000)
    IMM32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/IMM32.DLL (0x7ffbd3d70000)
    tmmon64.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/tmumh/20019/TmMon/1.6.0.1163/tmmon64.dll (0x6fa30000)
```

How should I go about troubleshooting this problem? I tried on a colleague's pc and he has the same problem.

Comment: don't use ldd, it will  not report missing dlls. Use instead cygcheck

Comment: @matzeri done. so it looks that no library is missing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cygcheck says that all dll's are in place, you can use
two ways to highlight a mismatch in library

You can use

http://www.dependencywalker.com/
or run

```
strace -o tunnel.strace stunnel
```

Comment: `$ stunnel -version`
`$ strace -o tunnel.strace ../../bin/stunnel.exe`
`Segmentation fault`
`$ stunnel -version`

Comment: look on the tunnel.strace for hints

Comment: file is empty :-(

Comment: strace -o tunnel.strace stunnel.exe . Without "../../bin/"

Comment: I will bet on an AV interfering on stunnel running

Comment: BINGO! The issue was with the AntiVirus. Once disabled, Stunnel is working correctly. Probably the AV received an update and since the past few days it must have blocked Stunnel.

Comment: For the history: which Antivirus ? I saw at least two similar cases in the last month.

Comment: The AV is Trend Micro